# ¿Cómo abrir PuTTYgen en Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Quisiera saber cómo puedo abrir PuTTYgen sin tener que utilizarlo exclusivamente desde la terminal. Es decir, cómo abrir el programa de tal forma que aparezca su interfaz propia.

Necesito esto ya que deseo transformar un archivo .pem a formato .ppk y no se cómo hacerlo desde terminal, ya que desde terminal solo sé crear un archivo .ppk nuevo, no uno a partir de otro .pem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se puede convertir de .pem a .ppk usando putty-tools:

> $sudo apt-get install putty-tools
>
> $sudo puttygen ppkkey.ppk -O private-openssh -o pemkey.pem

tomado de: https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/convert-pem-file-into-ppk/